# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got clob hibernate/springboot

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, blob

Using hibernate w/oracle to extract scoreboard data w/ avatar image stored as base64 LOB. I've done some research and it seems all of the other similar posts are people trying to make comparisons with CLOB data either by distinct or putting it in the where clause. I also read oracle doesn't support CLOB within a temp table(view), How else do I get the data from the database if this is the case. fyi the code works in H2 in memory DB.

query throwing error:

```
select distinct score.userId as userId, sum(score.totalScore) as totalScore, 
    sum(score.timeTaken) as timeTaken, user.image as image
from Score score, User user
where score.userId = user.userId
group by score.userId order by totalScore desc, timeTaken asc
```

entitities:

user:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence2")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_Sequence2", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ2")
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
int id;
int userId;
@Lob
String image;
Date createdDate;
Date lastLoggedIn;
```

score:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "quizID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
int quizId;
@Id
@Column(name = "userID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
int userId;
double totalScore;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=UserQuizRecord.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
List<UserQuizRecord> userQuizRecords;
int timeTaken;
int correctAns;
Date takenDate;
```

Comment: If the base 64 strings are less than 4000 bytes long you should be able to convert them to standard strings with `to_char`. Otherwise if you can't get Hibernate to restructure the query (I don't know Hibernate at all) then perhaps you could create a view over `Score` giving one row per `userID`. Oracle does support CLOBs in both temporary tables and views.

Answer (score 3):

Check this link.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=998284

As per this, `DISTINCT` cannot be used with `CLOB` datatype i.e. `image`. Please check if this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm not using distinct with image am I? I'm using it on the first select statement from the Score table. Then joining the view with the user table correct?

Comment: If this is the case how do I join the tables on userID then

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve the exact problem, but a workaround I used (which isn't ideal but works) is I got everything except the image data in 1 query then had another query for the image data and concatenated the image onto the end of the view afterwards. I'm only querying for the top 100 results so this isn't that taxing resource wise.